# How to allow public users to access my facebook chatbot using bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I was trying to access my `Facebook` chatbot through public user accounts. Using `Bot Framework` only for accounts added into developer, tester of the Facebook app can get a response from chatbot. But without adding user accounts to the app directly public user should get a response from chatbot.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will need to first submit your app for review in `Facebook` and once you pass the review, you will need to make your app public (and your page needs to be public too).

Take a look to the [Launching your Bot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/launch) documentation from Facebook.